# Embedding a google map instance based on the given address automatically

Tags: javascript, python, google-maps, iframe, embed

I want to have an `input` which gets user’s
given address and creates a **google maps instance** based on the given address,
And embed it in website.

Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76724173/edit) your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [full text of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), all as formatted text in the question itself. Do not post images of text. The code should be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The short answer is, yes, there is a way to implement this. The long answer is outside the scope of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the Maps API (first you need to sign up, create a project, and enable the "Google Maps JavaScript API" for your project).

To load the API, you need to include it in the `head` tag of your website.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- ... -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- ... -->
</body>
</html>
```

where `API_KEY` is your key.

Then, in the body, make the input tag with a button to call a javascript function to open the map

```html
<input type="text" id="inputted-address" placeholder="Type address here">
<button onclick="showMap()">Show Map</button>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Last, add javascript to define the function `showMap()` used above.  Something like this:

```html
<script>
  function showMap() {
    var address = document.getElementById('inputted-address').value;
    // convert the address to latitude & longitude
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ address: address }, function(results, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var location = results[0].geometry.location;
        // Create the map centred on the user-inputted address
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: location,
          zoom: 15 // initial zoom level (change if you want)
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: location,
          title: 'Inputted location'
        });
      } else {
        alert('Hmm. Seems there was a problem: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```